# hi am trying converting two dimentional array into three single dimentional array

Tags: java, arrays

hi am trying converting two dimentional array into three single dimentional arrays but how i dont know any one knows please help me

here my array is there

```
double[][] data= {{97, 36, 79}, {94, 74, 60}, {68, 76, 58}, {64, 87, 56}, {68, 27, 73}, {74, 99, 42}, {7, 93, 87}, {51, 69, 40}, {38, 23, 33}, {57, 86, 31}};
```

I want to get:

```
double[] xarry={97,94,68,.....}//first elements

double[] yarry={36,74,76,.....}//second elements

double[] bubble_size={79,60,58,.....}//third element
```

**Code snippet:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < bubble_Data.length; i++)
{
    if ( bubble_Data[i][0]>0)
        count++;
}
x_Array = new double[count];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bubble_Data.length; i++)
{
    if ( bubble_Data[i][0]>0)
    {
        x_Array[k] = bubble_Data[i];
        k++; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you have tried till now ?

Comment: Loop over the two-dimensional array and store the values `data[i][0]`, `data[i][1]` and `data[i][2]` into the respective array `xarry`, `yarry` and `bubble_size`.

Comment: @ChanduD You should edit your question, and include your attempt, instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: thanQ so much  subOptimal its working me

Comment: Thanq for all and suboptimal code is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not that difficult, if you have attempted it yourself.

- Get the length of the `data` array, create 3 1-D double arrays with that length.
- Traverse the `data` array, put the correct values in the 1-D arrays using index 0-2

**Code:**

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double [][] data= {{97, 36, 79}, {94, 74, 60},
                {68, 76, 58}, {64, 87, 56}, {68, 27, 73},
                {74, 99, 42}, {7, 93, 87}, {51, 69, 40},
                {38, 23, 33}, {57, 86, 31}};

        double [] xArr = new double[data.length];
        double [] yArr = new double[data.length];
        double [] bubbleSizeArr = new double[data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            xArr[i] = data[i][0];
            yArr[i] = data[i][1];
            bubbleSizeArr[i] = data[i][2];
        }

        // Test printing
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%5.2f %5.2f %5.2f%n", xArr[i],
                    yArr[i], bubbleSizeArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
97.00 36.00 79.00
94.00 74.00 60.00
68.00 76.00 58.00
64.00 87.00 56.00
68.00 27.00 73.00
74.00 99.00 42.00
 7.00 93.00 87.00
51.00 69.00 40.00
38.00 23.00 33.00
57.00 86.00 31.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added the sample code to get the values from the 3 dimensional array. It should be very simple. You can use the arrayList in Java to store the values. Extend the attached program and fix your issues.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("xarray - " + data[i][0]);
        System.out.println("yarray - " + data[i][1]);
        System.out.println("bubble - " + data[i][2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. Just go through and let me know in case you need some clarity.
public class ThreeDto2D {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] data= {{97, 36, 79}, {94, 74, 60}, {68, 76, 58}, {64, 87, 56}, {68, 27, 73}, {74, 99, 42}, {7, 93, 87}, {51, 69, 40}, {38, 23, 33}, {57, 86, 31}};

    double data1[] = new double[data.length];
    double data2[] = new double[data.length];
    double data3[] = new double[data.length];

    for (int x= 0;x < data.length;x++)
    {           
        for (int y=0; y < data[x].length ;y++)
        {
            if (y==0)
                data1 [x] = data [x][y];
            else if (y==1)
                data2 [x] = data [x] [y];
            else if (y==2)
                data3 [x] = data [x] [y];               
        }           
    }

    for (int i=0;i<data1.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(data1[i]+" ");
        System.out.print(data2[i]+" ");
        System.out.print(data3[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Output :

```
97.0 36.0 79.0
94.0 74.0 60.0
68.0 76.0 58.0
64.0 87.0 56.0
68.0 27.0 73.0
74.0 99.0 42.0
7.0 93.0 87.0
51.0 69.0 40.0
38.0 23.0 33.0
57.0 86.0 31.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am improving my code based on your suggestions.

```
public double[] getX_Array(double[][] bubble_Data) {
    double minValue = 0;
    double positiveValue = 0;
    int count = 0;

    x_Array = new double[bubble_Data.length];
    y_Array = new double[bubble_Data.length];
    size_Array = new double[bubble_Data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bubble_Data.length; i++) {

        x_Array[i] = bubble_Data[i][0];
        y_Array[i] = bubble_Data[i][1];
        size_Array[i] = bubble_Data[i][2];
    }

    System.out.println("single array of positve values " +
            Arrays.toString(size_Array));
    return x_Array;
}
```